# catch statement does not work SharePoint Online PNP

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I have written a powershell script which downloads files from sharepoint using PNP. This works fine however I am trying to do some error catching when the file does not exist add it to a csv however the error is not getting caught.
code below:

```
try{
        Get-PnPFile -Url $fileUrl -Path $fullExportPath -FileName $fileName -AsFile 

    }catch [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException]
        {             
            Write-Output "File not found: skipping to next list item...";

            $failedDocItem = New-Object System.Object;
            $failedDocItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Absolute_Url -Value $fileUrl;
            $failedDocItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SBI -Value $sbiFolderName;

            $failedDocItems += $failedDocItem;

            continue;
        }
        $error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName
         #write out CSV of failed XML Items (XML files not found in SharePoint)
    $outputFailedItemsCSVfilePath = $logFileDirectory + "\" + "Failed_MapFiles_Log_Output_" + $logfileDateStr + ".csv";
    $failedDocItems | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $outputFailedItemsCSVfilePath -Verbose;
```

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/

Comment: tried but still isn't caught

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue of not being able to catch exceptions with Add-PnPListItem. Running it in a variable and adding -ErrorAction Stop worked for me.

Using parts of the OP's script for this example, this is what worked:

```
try 
{
    $getTheFile = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileUrl -Path $fullExportPath -FileName $fileName -AsFile -ErrorAction Stop
    $getTheFile
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Issue occurred while getting: $($fileName):" -Foregroundcolor Red
    Write-Host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -Foregroundcolor Red
    $failedDocItems++
}
```